# VB.NET Error with parameterized query

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following code to import data from an CSV file to a SQL database table:

```vb
Dim folder = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\EZY Wine Data\"
Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from skedp_lb.csv", CnStr)
   Adp.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
   Adp.Fill(dt)
End Using



    Dim konneksie As New SqlConnection
    Dim opdragdelete, opdragreseed, opdragSitTipeIn As New SqlCommand
    konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    konneksie.Open()

    Dim strsql As String = "insert into ontledings_vyfjaar_histories (PLAASNO,BLOKNO,DATUM,SUIKER,SUUR,pH) values (@PLAASNO,@BLOKNO,@DATUM,@SUIKER,@pH,@SUUR)"

    Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Skedulering6\Skedulering6\SkeduleringsDatabasis6.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strsql, connection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@PLAASNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F1")
            .Add("@NAME1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F2")
            .Add("@BLOKNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F3")
            .Add("@NAME2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F4")
            .Add("@ANALISEDATUM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F7")
            .Add("@NAME3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F8")
            .Add("@DATUM", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "F9")
            .Add("@SUIKER", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F10")
            .Add("@pH", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F11")
            .Add("@SUUR", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F12")

        End With

        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()

        adapter.InsertCommand = cmd

        Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = adapter.Update(dt)

    End Using
    konneksie.Close()
```

However I get the following error code at the third line from the bottom ie adapter.Update(dt) :   Additional information: The parameterized query '(@PLAASNO varchar(50),@NAME1 varchar(50),@BLOKNO varchar(50),@NA' expects the parameter '@pH', which was not supplied.

A sample of my CSV (hope I am pasting it correct) :

```
plaasno,name1,blokno,name2,analisedat,name3,datum,suiker,ph,suur
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","1","VREDENDAL","20120307","","07/03/12",20.60,3.16,8.35
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","1","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",20.60,3.08,9.47
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","10","VREDENDAL","20120321","","21/03/12",22.80,3.28,8.17
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","10","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",20.60,3.09,10.24
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","11","VREDENDAL","20120131","","31/01/12",19.00,3.16,8.32
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","11","VREDENDAL","20120227","","27/02/12",22.40,3.46,6.01
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","11","VREDENDAL","20120308","","08/03/12",22.80,3.39,6.67
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","11","VREDENDAL","20120314","","14/03/12",23.20,3.39,6.41
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","11","VREDENDAL","20130215","","15/02/13",21.50,3.24,8.60
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","2","VREDENDAL","20120201","","01/02/12",16.80,2.93,12.45
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","2","VREDENDAL","20120220","","20/02/12",21.00,3.24,7.13
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","2","VREDENDAL","20130215","","15/02/13",21.20,3.08,9.31
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","4","VREDENDAL","20120131","","31/01/12",19.20,3.06,9.18
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","4","VREDENDAL","20120207","","07/02/12",22.80,3.20,7.62
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","4","VREDENDAL","20130208","","08/02/13",21.60,3.02,7.48
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","5","VREDENDAL","20120131","","31/01/12",18.80,3.10,9.54
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","5","VREDENDAL","20120201","","01/02/12",19.20,3.08,9.12
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","5","VREDENDAL","20120207","","07/02/12",21.60,3.23,7.53
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","5","VREDENDAL","20130208","","08/02/13",20.00,2.96,8.00
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","6","VREDENDAL","20120321","","21/03/12",21.00,3.14,8.11
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","6","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",20.00,2.94,8.74
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","7","VREDENDAL","20120321","","21/03/12",20.00,3.07,8.52
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","7","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",21.00,2.94,8.59
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","8","VREDENDAL","20120321","","21/03/12",21.80,3.26,8.42
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","8","VREDENDAL","20120326","","26/03/12",22.00,3.34,8.16
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","8","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",20.20,3.10,9.63
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","9","VREDENDAL","20120321","","21/03/12",22.30,3.50,4.98
"03002","BLOMVELD-SE-VLEI","9","VREDENDAL","20130225","","25/02/13",19.60,3.32,5.23
"03566","PERSEEL 101","UIT-22","VREDENDAL","20120323","","23/03/12",24.00,3.66,7.29
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","1","VREDENDAL","20120131","","31/01/12",18.60,3.11,9.09
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","1","VREDENDAL","20130221","","21/02/13",23.00,3.21,7.71
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","2","VREDENDAL","20120131","","31/01/12",19.20,3.12,9.40
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","2","VREDENDAL","20120207","","07/02/12",16.40,3.09,11.63
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","2","VREDENDAL","20120307","","07/03/12",19.40,3.34,7.15
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","2","VREDENDAL","20120326","","26/03/12",20.00,3.48,6.41
"03785","KOEKENAAP PER 420 & 797 & 798","2","VREDENDAL","20120402","","02/04/12",21.0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Regards

Comment: You flipped the SUUR,pH columns to @pH,@SUUR.  What are you doing with all those Command objects?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding more parameters than your query needs.

You should only add exactly as much parameters as you defined in your query. Not more, not less. Preferably add the parameters values in the same order you specified them in the query, since some DB Engines expects them like that.

I noticed that you have switched the places of the last two parameters.

You typed:

```
Dim strsql As String = "insert into ontledings_vyfjaar_histories
           (PLAASNO ,BLOKNO,  DATUM, SUIKER, SUUR, pH) 
    values (@PLAASNO,@BLOKNO,@DATUM,@SUIKER,@pH,  @SUUR)"
```

Notice that `SUUR` and `pH` are expected in a certain order, however, the parameter names are switched.

You should re-type it:

```
Dim strsql As String = "insert into ontledings_vyfjaar_histories
           (PLAASNO ,BLOKNO,  DATUM, SUIKER, SUUR, pH) 
    values (@PLAASNO,@BLOKNO,@DATUM,@SUIKER,@SUUR,@pH)"
```

Because your `insert` statement only expects `(PLAASNO,BLOKNO,DATUM,SUIKER,SUUR,pH)`, there is no point in adding a `NAME1,NAME2,NAME3,...`, etc parameters.

```vb
With cmd.Parameters
     .Add("@PLAASNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F1")
     '.Add("@NAME1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F2")         'Remove this line
     .Add("@BLOKNO", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F3")
     '.Add("@NAME2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F4")         'Remove this
     '.Add("@ANALISEDATUM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F7")  'Remove
     '.Add("@NAME3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "F8")         'Remove
     .Add("@DATUM", SqlDbType.Date, 50, "F9")
     .Add("@SUIKER", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F10")
     .Add("@SUUR", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F12")          'SUUR before pH
     .Add("@pH", SqlDbType.Decimal, 50, "F11")            'pH is last
End With
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad. I have removed the lines as you suggested. However I still get the same error.

Comment: I have found another problem. The order of the last two parameters are not correct. I edited my answer. See for more details @Gideon

Comment: Hi Ahmad. Thank you once again. Yes I saw that too and corrected it ( actually pH is before SUUR - it is like that in the database table). All the parameters are in the correct order now. Still getting the error?